# Laravel livewire DOM PDF the file save but not downloaded

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf, laravel-livewire

I am using DOM PDF to print the html invoice page, the method call by livewire method, The file save correctly to the public folder but I need to download it through browser instead of save it.

**Component blade view:**

```php
<div class="m-3 ml-auto">
    <button wire:click="exportPDF()" type="button"
            class="border border-indigo-500 text-indigo-500 rounded-md px-4 py-2 m-2 transition duration-500 ease select-none hover:text-white hover:bg-indigo-600 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
            {{ __('Export PDF') }}
    </button>
</div>
```

**Livewire Component method:**

```php
public function exportPDF()
{
   $order = $this->order;
   $view = view('order')->with(compact('order'));
   $html = $view->render();
   $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html)->save(public_path() . '/order.pdf');
   
   //return $pdf->download('download.pdf');
   //    $pdf= PDF::loadHTML($html);
   //     return $pdf->download('order.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @Alaa, I will try to help you writing an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use this method to create and download PDF

```
$data = [
            'company' => $company,
            'logo' => $company->logo ? $logo : null,
            'customer' => $this->customer ?? null,
            'charged' => $charged,
            'sumChargedDuration' => $sumChargedDuration,
            'sumCharged' => $sumCharged,
            'notCharged' => $notCharged,
            'sumNotChargedDuration' => $sumNotChargedDuration,
            'sumNotCharged' => $sumNotCharged
];

$pdf = PDF::loadView('partials.pdf_generate_connections', $data)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')->output(); //
return response()->streamDownload(
    fn() => print($pdf), 'export_protocol.pdf'
);
```

Comment: Prospero, nice answer! Did you try in a livewire component?

Comment: @ViníciusFagundes this was exactly in a Livewire component...the examples for Laravel controllers don't work the same for Livewire so I find this solution and was a hit!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer, redirect to you pdf file:

```
$this->redirect('/<filename here>');
```

In your case:

```
public function exportPDF()
{
   $order = $this->order;
   $view = view('order')->with(compact('order'));
   $html = $view->render();
   $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html)->save(public_path() . '/order.pdf');
     
   $this->redirect('/order.pdf');
}
```

Comment: @Alaa, if my answer helped you, please, considering mark as correct and also upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem statement:**    I generated pdf file and uploaded to s3 bucket.  But I'm not able to download that file but I'm giving the correct path. When i hit the url It download the file but i click on download button in livewire laravel,it doesn't download that file.

**Solution:**
How you will fix this issue.

```
Step 1: Added this index in filesystem under config folder

  'pdf' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'root' => 'pdf',
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        ],

Step 2 :  Add this in your downloading function
        return Storage::disk('pdf')->download($model_object->file_name);

Step 3: Add this namespace to your file. 
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```